# How to bind a plugin goal to another plugin goal

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

In my current project we use some plugins needed by other plugins parameters like properties-maven-plugin or buildnumber-plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>v0</version>
    <name>myProject</name>

    <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
    </properties>

    <build>
      <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
          <configuration>
             <files>
                <file>${basedir}/configurations/${env}.properties</file>
             </files>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>initialize</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>initialize</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>create</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
          <groupId>com.wakaleo.schemaspy</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-schemaspy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <configuration>
              <databaseType>mysql</databaseType>
              <database>${database.schema}</database>
              <host>${database.host}</host>
              <user>${database.user}</user>
              <password>${database.pwd}</password>
              </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

The problem is that when you execute directly a plugin goal, goals binded on the initialize phase (or validate) are not executed. So to generate schema spy we need to type:

```
$> mvn org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:read-project-properties schemaspy:schemaspy
```

We want to tell that properties plugin and buildNumber plugin need to be executed for every maven command so we can type:

```
$> mvn schemaspy:schemaspy
```

Is there a clean way to do that (without scripting) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way would be to bind the `schemaspy` goal to a lifecycle phase (particularly as you have already done this ffor the other two plugins), so then you can simply run something like **mvn package** and have all three plugins executed in the appropriate phases.

If you want the schmespy plugin to only be executed under certain circumstances, put it in a profile, then run **mvn package -P schemaspy** to activate it. The configuration to achieve this looks like this:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>schemaspy</id>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.wakaleo.schemaspy</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-schemaspy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>schemaspy</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <databaseType>mysql</databaseType>
        <database>${database.schema}</database>
        <host>${database.host}</host>
        <user>${database.user}</user>
        <password>${database.pwd}</password>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </profile>
</profile>
```

Comment: Never thought about it. I like it.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help me. Can we bind a goal to another goal? I need to compute the branch name using a plugin in the context of branching for a release. It would be strange to ask the developers to enable a profile and run a lifecycle phase in order to create a branch, when they would normally simply run 'release:branch'...