# maven plugin goals

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm developing a Maven plugin that will have provide 5 goals. You can either execute goals 1-4 individually, or execute goal5, which will execute goals 1-4 in sequence. I've been looking for a way to reuse (i.e. invoke) one Maven goal from within another, but haven't found it yet.

Of course, I could just have goalX delegate to ClassX for most of it's functionality, then when goal5 is invoked, it delegates to Class1...Class4, but this still involves a certain amount of code duplication in terms of specifying, reading and validating each goal's configuration.

Is there a way to reuse one goal within another?

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Will this solution help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393691/how-to-bind-a-plugin-goal-to-another-plugin-goal

Comment: @josek - no, my question is about how to invoke a goal programatically from with the source code of another plugin goal

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to reuse one goal within another?

AFAIK, the Maven API doesn't offer any facility for this because the Maven folks don't want to promote a practice leading to strong coupling between plugins which is considered as bad. You'll find background on that in [Re: calling plugin in another plugin?](http://markmail.org/message/jzwiogrdbm7gy7a6).

That being said, this [blog post](http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2009/06/executing-maven-plugin-from-maven.html) shows how you could instantiate a Mojo and use reflection to set its field before to call execute.

You might also want to check the [mojo-executor](http://code.google.com/p/mojo-executor/) library.

But be sure to read the mentioned thread, I think it's important.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course, I could just have goalX delegate to ClassX for most of it's functionality, then when goal5 is invoked, it delegates to Class1...Class4, but this still involves a certain amount of code duplication in terms of specifying, reading and validating each goal's configuration.

So then why not provide a common class for your other classes for the purpose of goal validation? I think the easiest thing to do here is to have one goal invoke the other in your code.

Comment: But my problem is that I don't know how to invoke one goal from another

Comment: What I am saying is that you should just call the code that handles goal1 from within the code that handles code5.

Answer (score 0):

The "Maven mindset" appears to be that configuration is the responsibility of the pom.xml author, not the Mojo implementor.  If you move all your configuration and such into a common base class, you end up bypassing this mechanism.

It kind of sounds like what you want are sub-projects: Each of your goals 1-4 live in their own project, or you can run goal 5, which runs them all.  Perhaps this might help?: http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/Maven/Maven+Recipes/Split+Your+Project+Into+Sub-Projects

If your source trees don't split nicely along project lines, you might be able to do something with profiles (though I haven't tried this).  Check out the accepted answer here: [How to bind a plugin goal to another plugin goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393691/how-to-bind-a-plugin-goal-to-another-plugin-goal).